new application application identifier error FCM version v1 not supported
In expo project credentials I am trying to create new application identifier, but after filling everything I am getting FCM version v1 not supported. Expo is not explaining v1 is not supported by what. I am not sure if problem is with my service file or react native configuration, or google-services.json. All I get is this. Please anyone had this problem?

If this message is displayed, it means you are posting wrong key. I have been trying to upload google service key in place of cloud msging key. After adding correct one, it worked.

Seems like something is wrong with the web app for uploading these. Try using the expo cli.
Run eas credentials
Select Android > production > Google Service Account
Select Manage your Google Service Account Key for Push Notifications (FCM V1)
